# C++ different declarations of an object

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have started learning C++ and totally confused of the difference between:

```
Array a(20); 
Array* ptr = Array(20);
```

I read that if the first was written inside a block it will be freed after the end of it automatically, but the second one will leak memory. But why is that? what each-one stands for?

Plus, how should I destroy each-one implicitly, is their a difference?

array.h:

```
class Array {
int* data;
int size;

public:
Array(int sz);
~Array();
int& atIndex(int index);
};
```

array.cpp:

```
Array::Array(int sz) {
data = new int[sz];
size = sz;
}

Array::~Array() {
delete[] data;
}

int& Array::atIndex(int index) {
 assert(index >= 0 && index < size);
return data[index];
}
```

Comment: `Array* ptr = Array(20);` -- That will not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Array a(20);
> ```

This declares a variable of type `Array`. It is initialised with the expression 20, which resolves to the constructor `Array(int)`. The storage class of the object depends on the context. If it is within a block scope, then the object has automatic storage. Objects with automatic storage are destroyed automatically at the end of the block.

> ```
> Array* ptr = Array(20);
> ```

Thie declares a variable of type `Array*` i.e. pointer to `Array`. This pointer variable also would have automatic storage assuming block scope, and it would be destroyed at the end of the block. Note that this destruction would have no effect on the pointed object.

Notice that I said "would" in previous paragraph. You attempt to initialise the pointer with the expression `Array(20)`, which creates a temporary object of type `Array`. But the `Array*` variable cannot be initialised with the initialiser because the temporary `Array` is not convertible to `Array*`. As such, this declaration is ill-formed.

---

The class `Array` is poorly designed.

It has a destructor which deletes a pointer member. A well designed class that has such destructor should maintain a class invariant, that the pointer value is always unique i.e. no instance of the class has the same pointer value as another instance.

This is because if the suggested invariant is violated, then the destructors of the instances with the same pointer will delete that same pointer, which results in undefined behaviour.

The copy (and move) constructor of `Array` violates this invariant; making a copy of `Array` creates another instance with a copy if the pointer member. Same also for copy (and move) assignment opeprator.

A solution is to implement a copy (and move) constructor and assignment operators that maintain the uniqueness class invariant. Better solution is to use a smart pointer instead of a bare pointer in which case the implicitly generated copy (and move) constructors and assignment operators would be good. You should avoid using owning bare pointers.

Comment: Thanks, last thing when I should declare an Array and when a pointer to an Array? what's the advantages?

Comment: @clark_smith1 They are fundamentally different things. When you need an instance of a class, then create an instance of the class. When you need to point to an instance of a class, then create a pointer.

Comment: so it's like c language when I wanted int and when I wanted a pointer to int right? (same idea)

Comment: @clark_smith1 Yes.